# Problema con la zonas de bind9

Tags: dns

Tengo un dominio con cuatro maquinas virtuales, dos servidores dns con bind9 y dos host, y tengo un problema con el fichero named.conf.local donde me suelta un par de errores al usar el comando `sudo named-checkconf`.

Salida del comando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estado del servicio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida del syslog
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los ficheros que he configurado son los siguientes:

named.conf.local

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

named.conf.options

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

db.2daw.edu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

db.10.0.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El dominio es 2daw.edu y la red es 10.0.2.0/24.

La cuestión es, viendo la información que pase en las correspondientes capturas, en que consiste ese error y como solucionarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el archivo `named.conf.local`, en la zona `2.0.10.in-addr.arpa`, te falta cerrar con `;` el `allow-query { any; }`.

Quedando así

```
allow-query { any; };
```